# Trouble Accessing JSON Data in a Javascript Function Within an Express/Jade Template

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm kind of new at Express/Jade, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I'm passing JSON data in to a Jade template, but, though the data is definitely there and usable elsewhere on the page, I can't seem to access it in a Javascript function within the same page.

The code in question looks like this:

```
script.
    function populateData(value){
        console.log("Value = " + value);
        for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++){
            console.log("i = " + i);
            if(value==i){
                console.log("school = " + mydata.sclist[i].sName);
                $('#input_sid').val(mydata.sclist[i].sID);
                $('#input_spc').val(mydata.sclist[i].sPostcode);
            }
        }
    }
form#form_add_booking(name="addbooking",method="post",action="/addbooking")
    table.formtable
        tr
            td
                span
                    b School Name
            td
                select#input_sname(name="sname" onChange="populateData(this.value)")
                    option.
                        ======    select    ======
                    each school, i in mydata.sclist
                        option(value=i).
                            #{school.sName}
```

So, in the above code the SELECT list gets correctly populated with school names from the JSON, but, when the onChange attribute fires the Javascript function, I get an 'Uncaught ReferenceError that 'mydata' is not defined.

What am I missing please?

Comment: I think you might be getting mixed up between server-side and client-side JavaScript.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, but the data seems to be available to the client since mydata.sclist is getting used in the each loop to populate the select list. Can I not access individual elements using mydata.sclist[i] ?

Comment: The `each` loop is server-side, everything in `script.` is client-side.

Comment: Ah yes, gotcha. Sorry I was indeed being dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `mydata` is passed to jade when rendering the page. The page is then returned from the server to the client (web browser) as rendered HTML. You can't then access `mydata` variable because it's used only on server-side to render the page. (Select is rendered on serve-side)

To be able to access the data **the way you want**, you'll have to render javascript variable in addition to your code above which can then be used on the client-side. (when select is changed)

```
const clientSideData = !{(JSON.stringify(mydata))};
```

Place this to very top of `populateData` (it converts JSON object to string) and then replace `mydata` references in the function with `clientSideData`. In this way you'll have access to the data even from client-side as you'll render javascript variable.

Comment: Excellent! I'd sorted out a work-around, but this way is far more elegant. Thanks!